# How to make pre-resolved promises continue the test syncronisely

Tags: jasmine, jestjs, babel-jest

If I have a bit of code that cause something to happen async but not as a root cause of doing something (can't wait for the callback), something that happens on loop (i.e. testing autosave) how would be the best way todo it.

Here is a failing tests example of roughly what im trying to achieve.

```
function myProgram(something, onEvent) {
    something().then(() => onEvent());
}

test('Promise test', () => {
  const onEvent = jest.fn();
  expect(onEvent).not.toBeCalled();

  const doSomething = () => Promise.resolve();

  myProgram(doSomething, onEvent);

  expect(onEvent).toBeCalled();  // Expected mock function to have been called.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have either to return the promise from your test

```
test('Promise test', () => {
  const onEvent = jest.fn();
  expect(onEvent).not.toBeCalled();

  const doSomething = () => Promise.resolve();

  myProgram(doSomething, onEvent);

  expect(onEvent).toBeCalled();  // Expected mock function to have been 
called.
  return doSomething
})
```

or use `async/await`

```
test('Promise test', async() => {
  const onEvent = jest.fn();
  expect(onEvent).not.toBeCalled();

  const doSomething = await () => Promise.resolve();

  myProgram(doSomething, onEvent);

  expect(onEvent).toBeCalled();  // Expected mock function to have been called.
})
```

Also have a look at the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html#content)